# Issue with Glue get_databases API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, botocore

When I use get_databases() API in boto3, I only get the first 100 databases. How do I get the list of all databases from Glue catalog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS Glue GET API calls retrieve only the first 100 elements. To get all the databases, you'll have to use pagination(Glue.Paginator). For Boto3, you can refer the documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Paginator.GetDatabases

It shows an example to create an iterator that will paginate through responses from Glue.Client.get_databases().